# Issue with JPA parameter binding after upgrading to spring boot 2.7.5

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

After Upgrading to spring boot 2.7.5 from 2.7.4, we can see that the NULL query parameters which involves "LIKE" clause are getting bound as empty strings and not as NULL. The same is  bound as NULL, if the query condition is "=".

For example

If the query is as below and the p_user_name is passed as NULL,
`select user from User where :p_user_name is null or userName = :p_user_name`

the parameter is properly getting bound as NULL,
binding parameter [1] as [VARCHAR] - [null]
binding parameter [2] as [VARCHAR] - [null]

Whereas  if the query is changed to like below
`select user from User where :p_user_name is null or userName LIKE :p_user_name`

the parameter is incorrectly getting bound as EMPTY Strings,
binding parameter [1] as [VARCHAR] - []
binding parameter [2] as [VARCHAR] - []

The existing functionalities are impact due to this.

Comment: What about just adding `or :p_user_name = ''`?

Comment: The change breaks existing code. `:arg IS NULL` was better than `:arg = ''` IMO.

Comment: Issue open in spring-data-jpa: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-jpa/issues/2683